# Can I travel to the US with an Indian ECR passport?

Tags: usa, indian-citizens, passport-stamps, ecr

I'm an Indian citizen going to USA for a master's degree. I've my passport but with ECR (Emigration Check Required) stamp on it (born after 1993) because there was difference between my mother's name in my birth certificate and other certificates. I want to know the consequences if I try to travel to USA with an ECR category passport.

What will happen if I book a direct flight which does not travel through Gulf countries (which I am not allowed to go to because of ECR stamp) and what will happen if I book a flight to USA going through Gulf countries?

Comment: As I understand it, ECR is only relevant if you are traveling to work in a foreign country. If you go for tourism or studies it is not a problem. And you are going to the US anyway, so ECR does not apply even if you were going to work.

Comment: Some language advice: "I've" can't appear at the end of a sentence like that. "I've" is typically used when "have" is functioning as a helping verb.  It is almost never used when have is the main verb, especially not in the US.

Comment: @phoog: Question edited.

Comment: @1binary0 you could also have changed "I've" to "I have" -- I am not quite sure what rule prevents the contraction of "I have" at the end of the sentence.  There seems to be a [relevant question](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/49336/when-the-contraction-cant-be-used) at English Language Learners, using the example of "I am" at the end of a sentence.

Comment: @1binary0 Please let us know what was your experience in this regard? Were you able to fly without any issue or extra hassle?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ECR is not something the US immigration is concerned with. It is only a formality for India; and it only applies **if you are traveling for work** and even then, to a limited set of countries which does not include the US.

Here is the official reference, from the [Ministry of Overseas Indian Affairs](http://moia.gov.in/services.aspx?ID1=105&id=m6&idp=104&mainid=73) (I have highlighted the relevant parts):

> Emigration Act, 1983 provides that no citizen of India shall migrate
>   unless he obtains emigration clearance from Protector of Emigrants.
>   Similarly, it has been recognized that certain countries (currently
>   17) do not have strict laws regulating the entry and employment of
>   foreign nationals. They also do not provide avenues for grievance
>   redressal. Thus they have been categorized as Emigration Check
>   Required (ECR) countries. **Hence, all persons, having ECR endorsed
>   passports and going to any of the 17 ECR countries for taking up
>   employment require emigration clearance. However, ECR passport holders
>   going to any ECR country for purposes other than employment do not
>   require emigration clearance.** No specific mention of ECNR is made on
>   the passports and the ones not endorsed as ECR, automatically belong
>   to ECNR category.

If you were to a take any GCC airline, you would be a transit passenger and ECR will not apply.

To put it bluntly; if you are able to exit the country, and you have a valid visa for the US - you should have no issues during your travel and on entry that have to do with your ECR.